# I am using react-native-ble-manager, BleManager.scan() is not returning a peripheral id or uuid on Android 12, but it is working on iOS

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, react-native-ble-manager

Using react-native-ble-manager package -- when performing BleManager.scan(), I am not getting back a peripheral uuid or id on Android 12.  I am correctly passing through params of (serviceUuid, scan seconds, boolean).  I am getting back a peripheral uuid on iOS but not on Android.  I have made sure all of my required permissions are included in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" tools:targetApi="s" />
```

Below is the response I get back from the device (with sensitive data removed for obvious reasons), as you can see, it's missing the peripheral uuid and and device name.

```
 {"advertising":{"serviceData":{},"serviceUUIDs":["XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX"],"localName":"XXXXXXXXXXX","txPowerLevel":-21,"isConnectable":true,"manufacturerData":{"bytes":[BTYES-ARRAY","CDVType":"ArrayBuffer"}}}
```

I am on React Native version 0.64.2

At some point, I was able to get the peripheral id on Android 12 but now its not working anymore.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

-Tried upgrading to latest version of react-native-ble-manager

Answer (score 0):

Have you checkout its example? If it works, maybe you could start modify the example code according to your very own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an Android permission issue, on Android 12 and above, BLE Manager needs Bluetooth_scan and bluetooth_connect permissions enabled.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34587122)